# Volume of region inside sphere and cone

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, volume, spheres

> Let $R$ consist of the points lying inside of the sphere $$ x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 3^2 $$ and inside the cone $$ z = \cot(\alpha)\sqrt{x^2 +y^2} $$ where $\alpha$ is $\arccos(\frac15)$ Find the volume of $R$.

So I used cylindrical coordinates and set the two equations for $z$ equal to each other, and got $z = \pm \sqrt{9-r^2}$ as the bounds for $z$. Then for $r$ I replaced the expression for $z^2$ which I got from the the cone equation with the $z^2$ in the sphere equation. I got $r = \pm \frac{3}{\sqrt{1+\cot^2(\alpha)}}$ as the bounds. I think the bounds for r is where I made some mistake but I don't know what exactly.

I'm aware you can solve this using spherical coordinates as well, but I would like to solve the problem using cylindrical coordinates, and particularly learn where i went wrong in this problem.

The answer should be some rational number times $\pi$.

Comment: Note that $\sqrt{1+\cot^2(\alpha)} = \csc(\alpha)$ and $1/\csc(\alpha)$ is quite simple.  Note that in polar and cylindrical coordinates you should have $0\le r<\infty$, so only the positive value of $r$ you wrote down is the appropriate limit of integration. Check your $z$ bounds, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HINT**

- The intersection between the cone and the sphere is for $z=\cot \alpha \sqrt{9-z^2}\ge0\\\implies z=\frac{3\cot \alpha}{\sqrt{1+\cot^2 \alpha}}$
- For symmetry we can set up the integral in two parts for $z\ge0$, notably

$$V=\int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^{\frac{3\cot \alpha}{\sqrt{1+\cot^2 \alpha}}}\int_0^{r_1(z)}r\,dr\,dz\,d\theta+\int_0^{2\pi} \int_{\frac{3\cot \alpha}{\sqrt{1+\cot^2 \alpha}}}^3\int_0^{r_2(z)}r\,dr\,dz\,d\theta$$

Comment: How did you find the bounds for $z$? I don't see how you can find an expression for $z$ that doesen't include $r$. We have $$r^2 + cot^2(\alpha)r^2 = 9$$

Comment: @Pame we have $z = \cot(\alpha)\sqrt{x^2 +y^2}$ and $x^2 + y^2=9 - z^2$ the we can solve for $z$.

Comment: Ok i see how you got to $z = cot \alpha \sqrt{9-z^2}$ but then which substitution did you use for $z$ to get $$z=\frac{\pm 3\cot \alpha}{\sqrt{1+\cot^2 \alpha}}$$ ?

Comment: I've squared both sides $z^2 = (cot \alpha \sqrt{9-z^2})^2$

Comment: How do you find the bounds for $\phi$ if you want to do it in spherical coordinates?

Comment: @Pame Oh I need to revise a bit, I didn't remember now all the details, I'll come on this later.

Comment: @Pame what about of a new OP, such that I can post a new full answer?

Comment: I think i figured it out. $$ \phi = arctan(\frac{r}{z}) = arctan(\frac{3sin(\alpha)}{3cos(\alpha)} = arctan(tan(\alpha)) = \alpha.$$

Comment: Yes, good! I'll add another aswer here then!

Comment: Btw, do you think it is possible to solve this with one integral in cylindrical coordinates? Or do you have to use multiple triple integrals?

Comment: @Pame for cylindrical coordinates you need a double integral since you have  adiscontinuity in the boundary, whereas in spherical coordinates we have only one integral. it is of course more simple in this way

Answer (score 1):

In spherical coordinates we should have simply

$$V=\int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^{\alpha}\int_0^{3}r^2\sin \varphi\,dr\,d\varphi\,d\theta$$

[image]

Comment: I don't think you need the $2$ in front, since the cone has only nonnegative values for $z$.

Comment: @Pame ah ok if we are considering only the upper part of course we cal eliminate the factor 2. This is also true for the previous integral!